# Слеш или дефис?

Tags: орфография

Оба варианта взаимозаменяемы?

> Мы должны знать спряжения, чтобы правильно писать форму будущего/настоящего времени глаголов.

> Мы должны знать спряжения, чтобы правильно писать форму будущего-настоящего времени глаголов.